# Swagger documentation not importing to Postman as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to document an API developed in `.NET Core API`.

This is the result view in Swagger UI.

[image]

This is the result view when I import the `Swagger.json` to PostMan.

[image]

As you can see they are not grouped into a `FueLogs` collection.

This is how I configure the Swagger Doc in Startup.cs

```
// Swagger API Explorer - You can browse and test the API: /swagger/ui/index.html
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "API",
        Description = "Documentation for API",
        Contact = new Contact { Name = "Dawood Awan", Email = "m.dawood@gmail.com" },

    });
    c.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));

    c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);

    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    var xmlFile = $"xPT.MyProj.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

    c.EnableAnnotations();

});
```

and this is how I document the API Controller.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "FuelLogs")]
public class FuelLogsController : BaseController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fuel log details
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="companyId">The company ID of the asset.</param>
    /// <param name="fuelLogId">The fuel Log ID.</param>
    /// <returns>Fuel log details</returns>
    /// <response code="200">The fuel log details `FuelLogDTO`</response>
    /// <response code="400">If an error occurs.</response>
    /// <response code="401">If user doesn't have permission to perform the action.</response>
    /// <response code="403">If the user doesn't have access to this resource.</response>
    [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "GetFuelLog")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FuelLogDTO), 200)]
    [HttpGet("{companyId}/{fuelLogId}")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "View Fuel Logs")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int companyId, int fuelLogId)
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get to import into Postman where each controller is grouped into a Collection?

Swagger.json

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"API","description":"Documentation for API","contact":{"name":"Dawood Awan","email":"m.dawood@gmail.com"}},"paths":{"/api/FuelLogs/{companyId}/{fuelLogId}":{"get":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Get fuel log details","operationId":"GetFuelLog","consumes":[],"produces":["text/plain","application/json","text/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"companyId","in":"path","description":"The company ID of the asset.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"fuelLogId","in":"path","description":"The fuel Log ID.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"The fuel log details `FuelLogDTO`","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/FuelLogDTO"}},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}},"put":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Update an existing fuel Log","operationId":"UpdateFuelLog","consumes":["application/json-patch+json","application/json","text/json","application/*+json"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"companyId","in":"path","description":"The company ID.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"fuelLogId","in":"path","description":"The fuel log ID","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"model","in":"body","description":"The details of the fuel Log","required":false,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/FuelLogDTO"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"If update is success"},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}},"delete":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Delete an existing fuel Log","operationId":"DeleteFuelLog","consumes":[],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"companyId","in":"path","description":"The company ID.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"fuelLogId","in":"path","description":"The fuel log ID","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"If delete is a success"},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}}},"/api/FuelLogs/fuelTypes":{"get":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Get fuel types supported by the system.","operationId":"GetFuelTypes","consumes":[],"produces":["text/plain","application/json","text/json"],"parameters":[],"responses":{"200":{"description":"List of fuel types supported by the system","schema":{"uniqueItems":false,"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Dropdown"}}},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}}},"/api/FuelLogs/detailedList/{companyId}":{"get":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Get a list fuel log. Will return fuel logs filtered by AssetIds, start and end date.\r\nWill only return the number of fuel logs mentioned in pageSize parameter.","operationId":"GetFuelLogs","consumes":[],"produces":["text/plain","application/json","text/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"companyId","in":"path","description":"The company ID of the asset.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"PageSize","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"PageNumber","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"SortDirection","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"SortBy","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"TempSortBy","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"TotalItems","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"CompanyId","in":"query","description":"The company ID of the asset.","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"SiteId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"CategoryId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"GeofenceId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"AssetId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"DriverId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"ReportId","in":"query","required":false,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"AssetIds","in":"query","required":false,"type":"array","items":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"},"collectionFormat":"multi","uniqueItems":false},{"name":"StartDate","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string","format":"date-time"},{"name":"EndDate","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string","format":"date-time"},{"name":"FilterDate","in":"query","required":false,"type":"string","format":"date-time"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"List of fuel log details `FuelLogDTO`","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/PaginationResponse[FuelLogDTO]"}},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}}},"/api/FuelLogs/{companyId}":{"post":{"tags":["FuelLogs"],"summary":"Create a new fuel Log.","operationId":"GetFuelLogs","consumes":["application/json-patch+json","application/json","text/json","application/*+json"],"produces":["text/plain","application/json","text/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"companyId","in":"path","description":"The company ID.","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"model","in":"body","description":"The details of the fuel Log","required":false,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/FuelLogDTO"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"The newly created fuel Log ID","schema":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"}},"400":{"description":"If an error occurs."},"401":{"description":"If user doesn't have permission to perform the action."},"403":{"description":"If the user doesn't have access to this resource."}}}}},"definitions":{"FuelLogDTO":{"type":"object","properties":{"fuelId":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"companyId":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"assetId":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"reference":{"type":"string"},"currencyId":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"currencySymbol":{"type":"string"},"fuelType":{"format":"int32","enum":[1,2,3],"type":"integer"},"fuelTypeName":{"type":"string"},"date":{"format":"date-time","type":"string"},"invoiceNumber":{"type":"string"},"odometerReading":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"pricePerLiter":{"format":"double","type":"number"},"quantity":{"format":"double","type":"number"},"total":{"format":"double","type":"number"}}},"Dropdown":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"stringId":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"}}},"PaginationResponse[FuelLogDTO]":{"type":"object","properties":{"totalItems":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"data":{"uniqueItems":false,"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/FuelLogDTO"}}}}},"securityDefinitions":{"Bearer":{"name":"Authorization","in":"header","type":"apiKey","description":"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\""}},"security":[{"Bearer":[]}],"tags":[]}
```

Comment: See [TagActionsBy custom tag or controller name](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/467).

Comment: Did anyone find a simple solution do group by controller?